# dereferencing string array element c

Tags: c++, string, pointers, fstream

I have an array of strings and inside a loop, I want to do something like this:

```
fstream in(fileNames[i], ios::in);
```

but that doesn't work. Although, when I try:

```
fstream in("some string",ios::in);
```

it works.

How could I accomplish the same thing, but with an array element?

Comment: string fileNames[NUMTABLES];
fileNames = "some text goes here";

Comment: Do you mean c or c++?  `ios::in` isn't valid c

Comment: `fstream` and `ios::in`? Why not `ifstream`?

Answer (score 1):

In the old C++, you have to pass a `char const *` to the fstream constructor, so say:

```
fstream in(fileNames[i].c_str(), ios::in);
//                     ^^^^^^^^
```

In C++11 this is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the definition of `filenames` as it's not quoted in the question. From your comment, `string fileNames[NUMTABLES]; filenames = "some text goes here;`, it appears that `string` is similar to a `char`. For creating a `fstream` object, we need to pass a `char *` where as from the aforementioned definition, `filenames[i]` gets converted to a simple `char` which might be the cause of issue.

To overcome this, please find a sample code where an array of strings is defined as below and `fstream` object is created successfully without any issues.

```
char filenames[4][32] = {"Just for testing purposes", "This is for stackoverflow", "Just for enabling", "This is nice program"};
fstream in(filenames[2], ios::in);
```

Another approach could be to employ `strtok` to break down your string i.e. `some text goes here` into smaller strings as `some`, `text`, `goes`, `here` as shown below

```
char *newstr = strtok(filenames, " ");
fstream in(newstr, ios::in);
```